# How to write at a specific position of a file in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a text file which writes `Hello, how are you? \n\n\n`.

I would like to append `I am Sam.` with the last two `\n`s removed.

The resultant sentence should be `Hello, how are you? \nI am Sam.`

How is this done in Python?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write at a particular position in text file without erasing original contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061909/how-to-write-at-a-particular-position-in-text-file-without-erasing-original-cont)

Comment: Removing the two `\n`s can be dealt with as its own matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can check methods of [file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) and see the to insert elements from the end, we can use the second argument of the seek function and then get the output.

```
with open("text.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("Hello, how are you? \n\n\n")
    f.seek(-2,2)
    f.write("I am Sam.")

with open("text.txt","r") as f:
    print(repr(f.read()))
```

OUTPUT

```
'Hello, how are you? \nI am Sam.'
```

Comment: The file already contains `Hello, how are you? \n\n\n` and we should not write it to the file again.  Can we try something like `f = open('text.txt', 'a')` `f.seek(-2,2)` `f.write('I am Sam.')` ?