# write to a specific place in a file - Python

Tags: python

I would like to know if it is possible to add a block of text somewhere else than at the end of a file? For example from a keyword?

Here is my code:

```
file_one = "/var/lib/odoo/projects/Odoo/ecole/files/"+folder+"/eleves.xml"
modified = os.path.getmtime(file_one)
modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(modified)
day_date = datetime.datetime.today()

mode = 'a'
if day_date.day != modified_date.day:
    mode = 'w'
    xml = xml_head + xml + xml_footer
with open(file_one, mode) as f:
    f.write(xml)
```

The xml variable is a block of text.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write at a particular position in text file without erasing original contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061909/how-to-write-at-a-particular-position-in-text-file-without-erasing-original-cont)

Comment: What keyword do you want to look for?

Comment: It is rather simple to overwrite data at any point in the file, but if you want to move the data there you will have read and re-write it until the end of the file.

Comment: I would like to place myself after this word:
</eleve>

Answer (score 0):

use a [parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) it will be easier, then dump your xml.

Maybe something like that :

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root_from_string = ET.fromstring(my_string)
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a bad idea: when you get a single character wrong, your XML will be invalid and unparsable. In almost all circumstances it's easier to just recreate the complete file from scratch. This will make your code easier to understand, and a lot more robust than any attempt to update the file partially in place.

Comment: I do not have a choice. My goal is to modify this file for sending by email in the evening to a precise herure. The next day the file disappears and we start again like this every day

Comment: Just read the existing file using ElementTree (see the answer of yoann guillard), adapt as necessary using ElemtTree and write the changed file as a whole back to the existing location.