# Adding a string(line) to the specidifc position based on some criteria(in Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have the following .sql file:

```
execute_all.log
set echo on
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
@@2019-03-26_DX_1.sql
@@2019-05-10_DX_2.sql
@@2019-05-10_DX_3.sql
@@2019-05-14_1600_DX_4.sql
@@2019-05-21_0900_DX_5.sql
@@2019-05-21_0900_DX_6.sql
@@2019-05-21_0900_DX_7.sql
@@2019-05-21_0900_DX_8.sql
SET SQLBLANKLINES OFF
spool off;
@@make_constraint.sql
```

everything, that starts from "@@" is a file Name, that is relevant to me.
In a list I have another following files:

```
skripts_to_deploy = ['2019-05-14_1600_DX_4.sql','2019-05-15_1500_DX_55.sql']
```

Criteria are the following:

- if file already exists, then skip the file
- If file doesn't exist, then go through the files line. If the date of the file(part after @@) of the file in `skripts_to_deploy` is less then in the next line, then add the line(Name of the file) into this place(and keep other lines as well, but shifted, if needed).

Here is the code:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\danyef"
skripts_to_deploy = ['2019-05-14_1600_DX_13.sql','2019-05-15_1500_DX_55.sql']    
level = 'DXIDS'
with open(level + "_EXECUTE_ALL.sql","r+") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line == "execute_all.log\n" or line == "set echo on\n" or line == "SET SQLBLANKLINES ON\n":
            continue
        for skript in skripts_to_deploy:
            if '@@' + skript in line:
                continue
            next_line = next(file)
            print(next_line)
            if next_line == 'SET SQLBLANKLINES OFF':
                file.write('@@' + skript + '\n')
                print("written SET SQLBLANKLINES OFF:",skript)
            else:
                next_line = datetime.strptime((next_line.split('_')[0]).split('@@')[1],'%Y-%m-%d')
                if datetime.strptime(skript.split('_')[0],'%Y-%m-%d')<= next_line:
                    file.write('@@' + skript + '\n')
                    print("written:",skript)
```

Important note: `next_line = datetime.strptime((next_line.split('_')[0]).split('@@')[1],'%Y-%m-%d')` just extracts date from the line in the existing file.

In my code it adds a line, but instead of the right place(based on criteria mentioned above) it does it at the end of the file.

Maybe some other from my side are missed, you are welcome to correct it.
Thank you in advanced.

**EDIT:** expected Output:

```
execute_all.log
set echo on
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
@@2019-03-26_DX_1.sql
@@2019-05-10_DX_2.sql
@@2019-05-10_DX_3.sql
@@2019-05-14_1600_DX_4.sql
**@@2019-05-15_1500_DX_55.sql**
@@2019-05-21_0900_DX_5.sql
@@2019-05-21_0900_DX_6.sql
@@2019-05-21_0900_DX_7.sql
@@2019-05-21_0900_DX_8.sql
SET SQLBLANKLINES OFF
spool off;
@@make_constraint.sql
```

Comment: Could you perhaps also add the expected output based on your inputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write at a particular position in text file without erasing original contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061909/how-to-write-at-a-particular-position-in-text-file-without-erasing-original-cont)

Comment: @norok2 added, take a look

Comment: @norok2 in the "duplicate", that you have sent, the question is about "replacement" of the line(in my case it's not). Moreover, conditions are different. It's not a puplicate

Comment: it is pretty much the same as far as filesystem is concerned... inserting is just a special case of replacing an empty string with a non-empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most filesystems do not support inserting data in place.

In general, you have 3 options:

1. use `file_obj.seek()` (only for replacing data)
2. load all file in memory and dump it back
3. create a temporary file which you modify as you go, and you copy back to the origin

Option 1 seems to be off the shelves, as you want to insert data.
Option 2 seems to be the most appropriate in your case, you just need to adapt your code accordingly (e.g. use string slicing and concatenation instead of `read()` and `write()`).
Option 3 would also be possible, but is generally more burden. However, it is especially useful if you you cannot fit the whole file in memory.

For completeness below is a sketch of the code for each option.

---

**Option 1**:

```
# file should be open as a binary to avoid messy offsets due to encoding
with open(filepath, 'rb+') as file_obj: 
    while True:
        line = file_obj.readline()
        if not line:  # reached end-of-file
            break
        if condition(line):  # for strings, use `line.decode()`
            position = file_obj.tell()
            offset = 0  # the offset from the beginning of the line
            file_obj.seek(position - len(line) + offset)  
            # new data must be `bytes`, for strings, use `new_data.encode()`
            file_obj.write(new_data)
            file_obj.seek(position)
```

---

**Option 2**:

```
with open(filepath, 'r+') as file_obj:
    text = file_obj.read()  # read the whole file
    ...                     # do your preprocessing on the text as string
    file_obj.seek(0)        # go back at the beginning of the file
    file_obj.truncate()     # disregard previous content
    file_obj.write(text)    # write data back
```

---

**Option 3**:

```
import shutil

with open(in_filepath, 'r') as in_file_obj, \
        open(out_filepath, 'w') as out_file_obj:
    for line in in_file_obj:
        # should actually reflect your logic here
        if must_insert_here():  
            # preprocess data to insert
            out_file_obj.write(new_line + '\n')

        # should actually reflect your logic here 
        if must_be_present_in_new():  
            out_file_obj.write(line)

# perhaps you actually want to use `copy2()` instead of `copy()`  
shutil.copy(out_filepath, in_filepath)
```