# How to replace specific bytes in a binary file - Python

Tags: python, binary, overwrite

I want to replace small blocks of data in a large binary file (could be dozens of gibabytes in size), therefore it is impractical rewriting the file again while changing a very small part of it. Ideally, I would like to just replace the blocks I want to change with new blocks at known byte locations to make it faster.

I have built the following function to achieve this, but it replaces the entire file (creating blanks before the blocks I am replacing) with the block I want to put.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
def change_block(filename, text, byte_location):
    with open(filename, 'r+b') as f:
        f.seek(byte_location)
        f.write(bytearray(text, "utf8"))
        f.close
    return
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061909/how-to-write-at-a-particular-position-in-text-file-without-erasing-original-cont

Comment: Last 2 lines don't do anything

Comment: Shouldn't we close the file later in the function? That way, it will be left open and having read data into memory.

Comment: When you use `with`, the file is automatically closed when it's no longer used.

Comment: The example in the link searches for some text at unknown byte locations, then make the replacement. In my case, the byte locations I want to change are known, and I don't need to read the block I want to replace. I just have the block to put into the file at well specified byte locations. In my problem, I have a binary file with a text header that I would like to replace in the byte locations 101-200. How this can be achieved without reading any blocks of the file? thanks.